# EJB connect an interface

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have two modules inside my project:

JBoss 6 server:

```
import javax.ejb.*;
@Remote
public interface srv_interface {
    public int test();
}
@Stateless
public class srv_class implements srv_interface {
    public int test()
    {
        return 999;
    }
}
```

The client:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] arg ) throws Exception
    {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099");
        Context context = new InitialContext(props);

        Object connectionFacadeRemote = context.lookup("srv_class/remote");
        srv_interface exampleService = (srv_interface) connectionFacadeRemote; // can't get srv_interface anywhere...
    }
}
```

Problem is client does not see srv_interface.
How to make visible 'srv_interface' for the client module?

Comment: Can you provide the error or the output console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the interface to the client module, remember that what you get from Context it is an implementation not the interface itself.

(By the way try to follow the [Java naming convetion for Classes][1])

[1]. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java